# Django - mysql IntegrityError 1062

Tags: python, mysql, django-models

I have a cron job that downloads data from MySQL every night at 3. I can test this connection and download and it works. Occasionally the download partially fails. (partial download) If I try and re-run the py script, it barks. Duplicate entry error for key 2.

I want to be able to run a script and erase only the entries for the previous night so I can rerun the script that populates the db. There are three other tables tied to this one. What is django going to do if is create a SQL script that deletes yesterdays records? Will it automatically delete necessary additions to the other tables, or should I do this in the script also?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/django/grease/greaseboard/management/commands/import_patients.py", line 27, in handle
    mrn = row.MRN,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 134, in get_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 449, in get_or_create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 463, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 551, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 203, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1576, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 910, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 114, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '000xxxxxxxx' for key 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea how large the work is, but for similar problem I used transactions alongside savepoints - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints

so given something like:

```
transaction.auto_commit(False)
try:
    for raw_input in streaming_filelikeobject.readline():
        product = do_work(raw_input)
        MyTable(**product).save()
except SomeFileIOError:
    transaction.rollback()
else:
    transaction.commit()
```

Another idea would be to have a batch_id column and assign that on the start of each batch.

For very large data sets, you could use something like Memcache/Redis for managing inventory.

```
transaction.auto_commit(False)
try:

   for raw_input in streaming_filelikeobject.readline():
       product = do_work(raw_input)
       if redis_conn.sadd("my_input_set", product['some_unique_id']):
           MyTable(**product).save()

except SomeFileIOError:
    transaction.rollback()
else:
    transaction.commit()
```

.sadd() is a Redis command that returns true if an element doesn't exist already in a redis set.

Please note I am typing this stuff of the top of my head so method django transaction method signatures may not be authoritative.